# TFS work item : setting a field required based multiple fields

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have a TFS form, where I need to set a field as required based on two fields when the state changes to closed.

```
<STATE value ="Closed"> 
 <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.T1">       
       <WHENNOT field="Microsoft.VSTS.T2" value="Yes">           
        <REQUIRED />        
       </WHENNOT>
</FIELD>
</STATE>
```

The above code works fine, when T2 is Yes, T1 is required. However, I need to add the following condition : When T2 is Yes and T3 is not NA, then T1 should be Required. Else it should not.

I know nested conditions are not allowed in TFS, but is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that nested conditions are not allowed in TFS, but TFS allows customer develop controls to be hosted in work item form. Those controls can implement various business logics or add additional functionality to work with the workitemform. You need to customize a work item control to achieve your requirement. More information, check https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/